# Nativescript-vue Video Player loading complete callback not working

Tags: mobile-application, nativescript-vue

I am building native mobile app using `nativescript-vue` and using `Nativescript-videoplayer` plugin .Well the player working well but loadingComplete callback function is not working.

```js
<template>
    <Page >
        <ActionBar title="test">
          <StackLayout orientation="horizontal"
            ios:horizontalAlignment="center"
            android:horizontalAlignment="left">
            <Image src="res://icon" width="30" height="30" stretch="aspectFill" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ActionBar>
        <StackLayout>
            <VideoPlayer ref="player" :src="video.file" autoplay="true" height="300" @loadingComplete="videoCompleted" @finished="videoFinished" loop="false" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
<script >
  export default {
    props:['video'],
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
    methods:{
        videoCompleted(){
            console.log('Loading Completed');
        },
        videoFinished(){
            console.log('Video finished');
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadingComplete` was changed to `playbackReady` and the other handler attaches to `finishedEvent`

```xml
<VideoPlayer
    @playbackReady="videoCompleted"
    @finishedEvent="videoFinished"
/>
```

The demo is quite outdated, but the [documentation](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-videoplayer) looks mantained.